# Is there an online vue template to plain JavaScript playground?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vue.js

TypeScript has a [online playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) where you can directly see your TypeScript code to plain JavaScript in action.

[image]

React community also has this babel [playground](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgBA9gdgYQDZgMYGsC8Bvey3oC-AfAFBRTAAOxAEgKZJIxQDuMATkiMAPQ2k-4CMSA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=true&timeTravel=true&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=react&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-syntax-bigint%407.4.4) where you can see your JSX get converted to plain JavaScript in action, and I know many React teachers are using this tool to help the student to understand what's under the hood.

[image]

In Vue, we have [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library), you can directly build a single file using this command

```sh
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib
```

But the output makes people really hard to understand what's going on, I know vue-loader injects some runtime on it, and inline your css.

Is there an easier tool to help people understand what's going on when your Vue template get's compiled?